# How to combine a 3d room with area description

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm sorry for my bad English.

I have an exact 3d model of my office, I need to make augmented reality application using Lenovo Phab 2 Pro in which I can navigate around the office in reality and the application. I need to combine the 3D office model with the data of the Area Description. I'm using Unity.
Since the application should work with very large rooms for a long time, it is necessary to use the Area Description to minimize the accumulation of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is figure out what reference point your Area File starts at (where is point (x=0,y=0,z=0).  Then load the Tango Camera Prefab to x=0,y=0,z=0.  After this you should load your 3D model of your room and move the 3D model around until it puts your Tango Camera Prefab to the actual starting position where your Area File has (0,0,0).  Make sure to have your **Relocalization ON** in your Unity Settings.

Comment: It seems I solved the problem, the "Data Marker" helped me. After scanning the room (in the scene it's the scene of AreaLearning), you need to place about 3 makers in different parts of the room, save these markers, all coordinates are saved in a .xml file, it is stored in the / sdcard/Android/data/com.company.productName/files/39142das-34g4-74gve23-9423090dc-893dj.xml

Comment: Open the.xml file and find their coordinates, then create these coordinates in the unity scene, now load the 3D model of the room and align it with these labels. The most important thing is to make the 3d model as accurate as possible, the 3D model must coincide with reality.